# Using class as object property name

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the below code Aptana is giving me "Missing name after. operator" but the code is working.

Can I use class as an object variable name. Also what are the reserved keyword for variable name.

```
response = JSON.parse(data);
alert(response.class);
```

Comment: See [this](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably a false positive in the Aptana error checking routine.  Still, you should not use `class` as a variable name as it's on the future JS [reserved word list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words).

Answer (score 1):

You should *definitely* not use `class` as some browsers (e.g. Safari) will throw an error *today* if you do.

Answer (score 1):

`class` is a future reserved word, so you should avoid using it as an object name as they may cause errors to appear, for example in Firefox in strict mode:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Answer (score 0):

`class` is a reserved (future) keyword. See [this article](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm) for further information.